# Setting Background Drawable to LinearLayout Results in OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, drawable

I am trying to set a drawable image as a background to a LinearLayout by stretching the image to cover the entire area, without distorting its proportions (meaning that some of the sides of the image may be out of the screen, which is fine by me).

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    LinearLayout mainLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_ll);

    Integer lWidth = mainLL.getWidth();
    Integer lHeight = mainLL.getHeight();

    // Read your drawable from somewhere
    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cash_bg);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
    // Scale it the LinearLayout's size
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, lWidth, lHeight, true));

    mainLL.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
 }
```

I am getting the layout's width and height in the `onWindowFocusChanged` instead of `onCreate`, because I heard otherwise they will return 0 (since the layout is not fully rendered in the constructor). The image is not that large so I don't know why this out of memory issue occurs. It's 800x945px JPG with 113kb size.

Here's the error log:

```
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at com.myapp.something.FVCalculator.onWindowFocusChanged(FVCalculator.java:66)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2346)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:5676)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:853)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-13 11:00:00.067: E/AndroidRuntime(2010):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Same when you use BitmapFactory.decodeResource() instead of the drawable kung fu? Also you should remember that you already have set the Background as onWindowFocusChanged() might be called often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like setting the background of the LinearLayout in the XML is not affected by this out-of-memory issue (maybe the image is loaded in a different manner).

Anyway in my case using just this solved it in the layout file solved it:

```
android:background="@drawable/cash_bg"
```

I don't know how it will center though (and if it will cover the entire container).

Answer (score 1):

I did an app also happened to the same issue when it was load many large images. And I found this is very helpful to me -

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

As I know, some way to reduce the memory consumed by bitmap -

1. Bitmap.Config - default it will use 32bit to display a bitmap, you can set it to 24 or 16bit
2. Bitmap.recycle () - if you have many, release the previous one and then load new
3. Reduce the width and height of your bitmap

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use Bitmap.recycle(). since when focus changes each time being rebuilt and bitmap memory is not freed.

Comment: The same error occurs. Although I forgot to mention that another extra error occurs in the log above the other lines, but I think it is not that much important: `TAG:dalvikvm-heap` `Out of memory on a 28906232-byte allocation.`